# shell - How to add one column data into the line less then two column

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Could somebody share some suggestion about how to insert data "T" into the line less then two column.

initial data:

```
A,a1
B,c
1,2
3
a
M,n
```

Expected Data：

```
A,a1
B,c
1,2
T,3
T,a
M,n
```

Thanks a ton and have a good weekend.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NF==1 { printf "T,%s\n", $0; next } 1' input.txt
```

or

```
awk '{print ($0 ~ /,/) ? $0 : "T,"$0}' input.txt
```

output:

```
A,a1
B,c
1,2
T,3
T,a
M,n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your solution is very powerfull.

I am not good at awk advanced Usage. After several hours test and search some case,I write a  clumsy approach:

Comment: for i in `awk -F, '{if(NF < 2){print NR}}' colum.txt` ;do
 sed -i ''${i}'s/^/T,/g' colum.txt;

 done

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have some file called *test.txt*, you could do the following, e.g. as a bash script in the same folder as the file:

```
input=$(cat test.txt)
while IFS= read -r line; do
    substr=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f 1 -s)
    if [[ "$substr" == "" ]]; then
        newline="T,$line"
        echo "$newline" >> test2.txt
    else
        echo "$line" >> test2.txt
    fi
done <<< "$input"
```

The answer is written into a new file. Does that help?

Comment: try: `sed '/,/!s/^/T,/'`